# Check how many element between ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div,

```
<div id=refer_friends>
    <input type='text' name='refer1'>
    <input type='text' name='refer2'> 
    <input type='text' name='refer3'>
</div>
```

How to check, how many input elements between DIV refer_friend?

I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#refer_friends :input').length;
```

When you say 'input elements', this will get all input elements. Use the `input[type=text]` or `:text` to get only text elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#refer_friends").find("input[type='text']").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($("#edit_changes *:text").size());
```

problem fixed